# How to implement ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback from HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, x509certificate2, httpclienthandler

I'm trying to implement a method for `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` for an instance of `HttpClientHandler` class. I'm at a loss here because I don't know what to validate. I need to send a certificate to the server (which I'm already doing), as well as **validate the certificates the server sends me**. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914305/best-practices-for-using-servercertificatevalidationcallback) and [this](https://www.meziantou.net/custom-certificate-validation-in-dotnet.htm) implementations, which tell me to compare the received certificates with a known value. I'm not sure how to get this known value, I know that I have a trusted certificate installed in the *LocalMachine's Trusted root store*, should I expect a certificate from the chain to contain the same hash of my installed certificate?

Here's what I have so far:

```
private HttpClientHandler CreateHandler()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
    };
    var certPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MY_CERT_PATH"];
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(certPath, "tls.pfx")));
    handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
    return handler;
}

private bool ValidateServerCertificate(HttpRequestMessage message, X509Certificate2 certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policy)
{
    if (policy == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;

    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements)
        {
            var hashes = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, element.Certificate.Subject, true)
                .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                .Select(cert => cert.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName.SHA512));
            var hash = element.Certificate.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
            if (hashes.Any(h => h == hash))
                return true;
        }

        store.Close();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to solve a non-existent problem. If you don't know what to validate, why you ever bother with this? Before implementing validation you need to have defined validation requirements first.

Comment: If you don't register a validator you get the default: The cert is not expired, it is appropriate for the host you were trying to contact, and it chains up to a trusted root.  Sounds like you want the default.